# How to import jupyter notebook to another jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

So I'm trying to make a series of educational coding using jupyter. I wanted to create segmented parts by parts for exp. part1.ipynb, part2.ipynb, and so forth.

so when i use

```
from partuno import *
```

It returns an error and does not read the previous part even though they share the same folder location in jupyter. My question is are there any other way for me to import them into the next part?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "import_ipynb" library of python.
if you want to use the contents of one.pynb in two.pynb then

```
import import_ipynb
import one.pynb
```

now you can use the functions defined in one.pynb in you two.pynb

Comment: ok, when I tried that while installing pip install import-ipynb on to the jupyter notebook it shows that I need to restart and when I did just that it kept giving me the same notice that I need to restart the kernel

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1.

`pip import_ipynb`

### Step 2.

import your file at jupyter notebook.
[image]

### Step 3.

import `my_math.ipynb` file at `test.ipynb`.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Install package

```
pip install import-ipynb
```

## Import

```
import import_ipynb
import mypage
#import mypage.ipynb
```

## Use the functions

```
a = mypage.test1()
print(a)
```